# Linear regression with faster decrease in coefficient error/variance?

Tags: regression, estimation, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, standard-error

Suppose we have set of variables $Y$ and $X$, which know are related by a linear relation $y_i=\alpha x_i +\beta$, and important for us is to find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the error in estimating them.

I know that the simple linear regression leads to an estimate whose error decreases sub-linearly with the number of samples, i.e. $e \propto \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $. My question is that is there any other regression algorithm that does better than that, yielding linear or quadratic error?

Answer (score 2):

In general, no: OLS may be the efficient (see the Gauß-Markov theorem) estimator under certain assumptions, so there cannot generally be an estimator with a faster convergence rate.

To answer a slightly different question: there are setups under which even simple regression has a faster convergence rate. For example, if $x_i=i$ (a "time trend"), it can be shown that $$\hat\alpha-\alpha=\mathcal{O}_p(n^{-3/2})$$

Comment: Have you a reference for this rate of convergence, I'd like to see how it was obtained.

Comment: See, e.g., Hamilton, Time Series Analysis, Section 16.1.